# Prove that the binary operation a*b=a does not contradict the theorem 2.1.8

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Suppose we have the binary operation ∗ defined on ℝ by  ∗  = . Then every  ∗  =  for every  ∈ ℝ. For example,  ∗ 2 =  and  ∗ 7 = . Why doesn’t this contradict Theorem 2.1.8

Theorem 2.1.8: Let  be a set with a binary operation ∗. If there exists an identity element  ∈ , then it is unique.

I am having a hard time showing why this operation doesn't violate theorem 2.1.8

Comment: What do mean by an "inverse element"?    Do you mean an "identity element"?

Comment: yes I meant an identity element

Comment: Ok.  Does your binary operation have an identity element?

Comment: yes it stated that the identity element exists

Comment: Where is that stated?

Comment: Every element is a _right_ identity, but there is no _left_ identity.

Comment: See this is why I can't answer it. It seems my professor is not clear

Comment: I don't see what your professor has to do with this...you have given an explicit binary operation on $\mathbb R$.  If you think it has an identity element, which real number do you think it is?  Remember:  identity elements have to be two-sided.

Comment: To stress:  Theorem $2.18$ says $\textit {if}$ an identity element exists.  The Theorem says nothing about binary operations for which there is no identity element.

Comment: so it doesnt violate the theorem because there is no identity element?

Comment: Well, you have to show that it has no identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $a * 2 = a$ shows that $2$ is a right identity element, not an identity element. Similarly for $7$. There is no theorem saying that a right identity element is necessarily unique.

(However, Theorem 2.1.8 can be extended to the slightly more general statement that if a binary relation has a left identity element and a right identity element, then these two elements are equal. Thus, **in the presence of a left identity element**, it is indeed true that the right identity element is unique (if it exists), because any two right elements would have to both be equal to the left identity element. But your relation $*$ has no left identity element, so nothing forces the right identity element to be unique.)

Comment: so you are saying that there is no identity element

Comment: @K.Gibson: Yes, that's what I'm saying. A right identity element is (in general) not an identity element.

Comment: how do I show that

Comment: Well, you have shown that already! You have found two right identities that cannot both be identities, since two identities would be equal.

Comment: Makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be any set, equipped with the operation $xy = y$ for all $s, y \in S$. This operation is associative and hence $S$ is a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup). However, if $S$ contains at least two elements, then $S$ is not commutative and has no identity (an element $1$ of a semigroup $T$ is an *identity* if $1x = x = x1$ for all $x \in T$).

However, it is possible to add an identity to your semigroup $S$ by adding a new element $1$ to $S$ and by setting $1x = x = x1$ for all $x \in S \cup \{1\}$. I let you verify that $1$ is the (unique) identity of $S \cup \{1\}$. No contradiction with the given theorem.